# X-Okta-XsrfToken and JS Widget

Tags: csrf, okta, okta-api

I've noticed that when JS component makes calls to authorise (/api/v1/authn) its got an empty header in the request called 'X-Okta-XsrfToken'.

Should that be set or is it defunct?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug - X-Okta-XsrfToken isn't needed in the /authn requests. I've filed this issue for the team to fix:
https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/issues/359